# Prove that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to show that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ by letting $f(z)=\frac{1}{z\sqrt{z^2-1}}=\frac{1}{z}e^{-\log(z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$.

and I need to show that, on the 4 straight lines, $$L_1^+=\{z|z:R+\epsilon i \rightarrow \rho+1+\epsilon i\}, L_1^-=\{z|z:\rho+1-\epsilon i \rightarrow R-\epsilon i\}, $$$$L_2^+=\{z|z:-\rho-1+\epsilon i \rightarrow -R+\epsilon i\}, L_2^-=\{z|z:-R+\epsilon i \rightarrow -\rho-1+\epsilon i\}$$, which are the parts of a simple closed contour which is surrounding the simple pole $z=0$ of $f$ and excluding $\{x\in R | x$ is less than or equal to $-1$ or $x$ is greater than or equal to $1 \}$,
$$\lim_{\rho\rightarrow 0,R\rightarrow \infty, \epsilon\rightarrow 0 }\int_{L_{1,2}^{+,-}}f(z)dz=-\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
it is negative since I chose the contour negatively oriented at the first.
I was able to show that the other parts go to $0$, but somehow those four line integrals cancel out each other and make me crazy.

specifically, I got the following results:

$L_1^+ \rightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2}$

$L_1^- \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$

$L_2^+ \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$

$L_2^- \rightarrow -\frac{\pi}{2}$

I think the problem is to choose new branch cut when I make $\epsilon$ go to $0$. if $z=\sigma e^{i \phi}$ and $(z^2-1)^\frac{1}{2}=r e^{i\theta}$, then $2\theta=Arg(\sigma^2 e^{2i \phi}-1)$, so $\theta$ behaves similarly with $\phi$, and from here the above results come out and I don't know where I did wrong.

I know the other methods like letting $u=\sqrt{x^2-1}$, but I just want to do it this way to get used to it. any helps or hints? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the contour of integration and the signs of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ near the real axis. For large $|z|$, in the upper half-plane, $\sqrt{z^2-1}\approx+z$, whereas in the lower half-plane, $\sqrt{z^2-1}\approx-z$. Note that along the imaginary axis, $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is positive imaginary, so at $z=0$, we have $\sqrt{z^2-1}=+i$.

This means that $\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z\sqrt{z^2-1}}\right)=-i$.

[image]

The integral along the blue contours vanishes. On the large blue circles, the size of the integrand is $\sim\frac1{|z|^2}$ and on the small blue circles, the size of the integrand is $\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2|z-1|}}$ and $\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2|z+1|}}$

The integral along each of the red and green contours is the integral we want due to the signs of $z$, $\sqrt{z^2-1}$, and the direction of the contour.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
4\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z\sqrt{z^2-1}}
&=2\pi i\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac1{z\sqrt{z^2-1}}\right)\\
&=2\pi
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z\sqrt{z^2-1}}=\frac\pi2
$$

Comment: Very nice answer. (+1). I somehow missed the fact that the target integral appears twice on the left branch cut.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would treat this is using

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} 
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogA}(z+1))
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogB}(z-1))$$

with $\mathrm{LogA}$ the branch with argument from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ and
$\mathrm{LogB}$ the branch with argument from $0$ to $2\pi$. The first
logarithm has branch cut $(-\infty, -1)$ on the negative real axis and
the second one from $[1,\infty)$ on the positive real axis.

We use the contour integral

$$ \int_\Gamma f(z) dz$$

where $\Gamma$  consists of six components namely  a circle $\Gamma_0$
$1+\epsilon  e^{i\theta}$ centered  at one  with  $0\lt\theta\lt 2\pi$
traversed clockwise, a line segment $\Gamma_1$ just above the cut from
$\mathrm{LogB}$  connecting to  $\Gamma_0$  and continuing  up to  the
point  $R$ on  the positive  real  axis, a  quarter circle  $\Gamma_2$
parameterized by  $Re^{i\theta}$ with $0\lt\theta\lt  \pi/2$ traversed
counterclockwise and  connecting $\Gamma_1$ to  the point $iR$  on the
imaginary axis, a line segment  $\Gamma_3$ connecting $iR$ to $-iR$ on
the  imaginary  axis, a  quarter  circle  $\Gamma_4$ parameterized  by
$Re^{i\theta}$ with $-\pi/2\lt \theta\lt 0$ traversed counterclockwise
and  finally  a  line  segment   $\Gamma_5$  just  below  the  cut  of
$\mathrm{LogB}$ connecting $\Gamma_4$ to $\Gamma_0.$

Call the target integral $J$ i.e.

$$J = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx.$$

Now along $\Gamma_1$ we get

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{x} 
\exp((-1/2)\log(x+1))
\exp((-1/2)\log(x-1))
= \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

while on $\Gamma_5$ we obtain

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{x} 
\exp((-1/2)\log(x+1))
\exp((-1/2)\log(x-1)+(-1/2)2\pi i)
\\ = \exp(-\pi i))\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}
= -\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$

Therefore the contribution from $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_5$ in the limit
is $2J.$ We then obtain

$$2J = 2\pi i \times \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z)$$

if we can show that the remaining contributions vanish/cancel. Note
however that

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z) =
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogA}(1))\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogB}(-1))
\\ = \exp((-1/2)\pi i) = -i$$

so that this yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
J = \pi i\times \frac{1}{2} \times (-i)
= \frac{\pi}{2}.}$$

which  is the  desired result.   (Here we  have used  the  property of
$\Gamma_3$ being a line segment  passing through the pole at $z=0$ and
hence picking up half the residue.)

To  conclude  we  must   examine  the  remaining  segments  of  the
contour. To apply the ML bound to $\Gamma_0$ we observe that

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}}
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogA}(2+\epsilon e^{i\theta}))
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogB}(\epsilon e^{i\theta}))\right|
\\ \le \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}
\exp((-1/2)\log(2-\epsilon))
\exp((-1/2)\log(\epsilon))$$

where we  have used the fact  that the imaginary term  produced by the
two logarithms being exponentiated has modulus one. ML now yields

$$2\pi\epsilon \times \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\epsilon}} \frac{1}{\sqrt\epsilon}
\rightarrow 0 \quad\text{as}\quad \epsilon\rightarrow 0.$$

For $\Gamma_2$ and  $\Gamma_4$ we get (these are  alike and we discuss
$\Gamma_2$)

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+R e^{i\theta}}
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogA}(1 + R e^{i\theta}))
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogB}(-1 + R e^{i\theta}))\right|
\\ \le \frac{1}{R-1}
\exp((-1/2)\log(R-1))
\exp((-1/2)\log(R-1))$$

so that ML yields

$$\frac{1}{4}\times 2\pi R\times
\frac{1}{R-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{R-1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{R-1}} 
\\ = \frac{1}{4}\times 2\pi R\times
\frac{1}{(R-1)^2}
\rightarrow 0 \quad\text{as}\quad R\rightarrow \infty.$$

We now  show that  the contribution from  $\Gamma_3$ is zero  where we
will traverse  clockwise to simplify the  notation. We have

$$f(it) = 
\frac{1}{it}
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogA}(it+1))
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogB}(it-1))
\\ = \frac{1}{it}
\exp((-1/2)\log\sqrt{t^2+1}+(-1/2)i\mathrm{ArgA}(it+1))\\ \times
\exp((-1/2)\log\sqrt{t^2+1}+(-1/2)i\mathrm{ArgB}(it-1)).$$

Observe   however    that   when   $\mathrm{ArgA}(it+1)=\theta$   with
$-\pi/2\lt\theta\lt\pi/2$ we have $\mathrm{ArgB}(it-1)=\pi - \theta$

so that this simplifies to

$$f(it) = 
\frac{1}{it} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}
\exp((-1/2)i(\theta+\pi-\theta))
= -\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2+1}}.$$

Supposing  we make  a  semicircular indentation  of radius  $\epsilon$
around  the  singularity  at  $t=0$  we  get  for  the  upper  segment
parameterized by $z=it$

$$\int_\epsilon^R f(it) i\; dt.$$

We get for the lower segment

$$\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} f(it) i\; dt
= -\int_R^\epsilon f(-iu) i\; du
= \int_\epsilon^R f(-iu) i\; du
= -\int_\epsilon^R f(iu) i\; du.$$

The  two segments  cancel  for a  net  contribution of  zero. We  have
examined all six constituents of  the closed contour $\Gamma$ and this
concludes the argument showing that $J=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

**Addendum,  Oct  8  2016.**  In   order  to  justify  the  segment
$\Gamma_3$ passing  through the pole  at $z_0 =  0$ we observe  that a
function $f(z)$ with a simple pole at $z_0$ has the form

$$f(z) = F'(z) + \frac{1}{z-z_0} \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z)$$

with $F(z)$ analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0.$ Now by making a small
semicircular indentation $\Gamma_3'$ that is parameterized by $z=z_0 +
\epsilon e^{i\theta}$  with $\theta$ ranging from  $\pi/2$ to $-\pi/2$
so as  to capture the  inner angle we  get for the integral  of $f(z)$
along the semicircle with $F(z)$ analytic

$$F(z_0-i\epsilon) - F(z_0+i\epsilon)
+ \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z) \times 
\int_{\Gamma_3'} \frac{1}{z-z_0} dz
\\ = F(z_0-i\epsilon) - F(z_0+i\epsilon)
+ \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z) \times 
\int_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2} \frac{1}{\epsilon\exp(i\theta)}
i\epsilon\exp(i\theta) \; d\theta
\\ = F(z_0-i\epsilon) - F(z_0+i\epsilon)
+ i \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z) \times 
[\theta]_{\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}.$$

This becomes

$$-\pi i \mathrm{Res}_{z=z_0} f(z)$$

as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0.$ We thus obtain

$$2J - \pi i \times (-i) = 2\pi i \times 0$$

or  $2J  - \pi  =  0$  as before.  This  material  is  from this  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075962/)    and    this
[German                        complex                       variables
PDF](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/teaching/VertFunktionentheorie/Skript-VertFunktionenth.pdf).

**Addendum, Oct  9 2016.** The excellent answer  by @robjohn states
the contributions on  the two horizontal segments above  and below the
left branch cut without proof. It  may be interesting to see how these
are computed. Starting again from

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z} 
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogA}(z+1))
\exp((-1/2)\mathrm{LogB}(z-1))$$

we take a point on the negative real axis $x < -1$ and get from above

$$\frac{1}{x} 
\exp((-1/2)\log(-x-1)+(-1/2)i\pi)
\exp((-1/2)\log(-x+1)+(-1/2)i\pi)
\\ = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{(-x)^2-1}} \exp(-i\pi)
= - \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$

The contribution is thus

$$- \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx
= - \int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{1}{(-u)\sqrt{u^2-1}} (-1) du
\\ = - \int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}  du
= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}  du = J.$$

On the other hand we get from below

$$\frac{1}{x} 
\exp((-1/2)\log(-x-1)+(-1/2)(-i\pi))
\exp((-1/2)\log(-x+1)+(-1/2)i\pi)
\\ = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$$

The contribution is now

$$\int_{-1}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} dx
= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{(-u)\sqrt{u^2-1}} (-1) du
\\ = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}  du = J.$$

Comment: Does $\Gamma_{3}$ intersect the point $z=0$? I'm having difficulty understanding why that doesn't cause any trouble.

Comment: This is the Cauchy Principal Value as presented e.g. at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251825/) which says that the contribution from a line through a pole is $\pi i$ times the residue. The contour is indented in the part where I prove that the contribution from $\Gamma_3$ vanishes.

Comment: When you have $f(z)$ on $\Gamma_5$, since $\Gamma_5$ is approaching from the below the real line, shouldn't we take the branch cut of $log(z+1)$ to include $2\pi$, like $\pi < \theta < 3\pi$? the difficulty I'm having here is this; it makes $\Gamma_5$ cancel $\Gamma_1$ out.

Comment: @JessicaK I have added some additional material to address your question.

Comment: @JohnSnow You need to consider the factor resulting from the logarithm on $\Gamma_5,$ it prevents cancellation (factor shown above).